# How to deal with useEffect when it depends on HTTP response

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

In a React Native app, I have a component that shows a list of items. When the user adds a new item, an HTTP request sends this new item to the backend, which stores it in the database. While that's happening, the front-end is redirecting the user to the items list, where the items are fetched from the backend.

In this items list component, I have a `useEffect` currently as so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(auth.userId, auth.accessToken, axiosPrivate)
  }, [fetchItems])
```

This `fetchItems` is a redux action responsible for the HTTP request that fetches the items.

But when the user gets to the list the new item isn't there. If the user reloads the app then it's there. I'm guessing it has to do with the time it takes for the data to be updated by the HTTP request.

I have this in my redux reducer:

```js
case ADD_ITEM_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false
    };
```

I tried to use the `isLoading` information to control this behavior but couldn't manage to do it.

What should I do to guarantee updated data?

---

EDIT:

I tried to wait on the function that adds the item (through axios) before navigation but it didn't work.

This is the code that does it:

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {

    try {
        await addDish(auth.userId, auth.accessToken, data, axiosPrivate);
        navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [
                    { name: 'Home' },
                ],
            })
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could show your redirect to the items list? If your database setting method accepts a callback or is Promise-based; then you can wait for the database setting action to complete before redirecting.

Comment: I added it to the question, @PhantomSpooks. I tried to wait for the action but couldn't make it work.

Comment: If @ohto answer did not work, you could add a callback parameter to `addDish`; and then inside `addDish` after awaiting for the axios call to complete call the callback